# [Linux Difference between SUID and cap_setuid of binary]

Tags: linux, setuid, linux-capabilities, suid

"I dont understand difference between SUID of binary and cap_setuid in linux.Then, difference between SUID and setuid"

Answer (score 2):

SUID for a binary means that the binary is instrumented to become a different effective user when started. For example:

```
$ cp `which id` nobody_id
$ sudo chown nobody nobody_id
$ sudo chmod +s nobody_id
$ ./nobody_id
.... euid=65534(nobody) groups= ...
```

You can do the same thing but make the binary setuid-`root` to make the binary run with `root`'s privileges.

`CAP_SETUID` is a Linux capability to permit a process to change UID from code: it can give the code permission to execute the `setuid()` system call. This is considered a privilege over what normal user code can do. It can be given to a program using a file-capability that doesn't affect the ownership of the file:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_setuid=ep my_program_binary
```

When `./my_program_binary` is next run, it will run with that capability enabled.